# Access non-public (java-native) classes from JDK (7)

Tags: java, reflection, private, java-7

I want to use the method MethodHandleNatives.getTargetMethod(MethodHandle)AccessibleObject.
The class MethodHandleNatives is not public.
So does anybody know how I can do that?

I know that its possible to access private methods and fields via reflections, so I am asking, if this is also possible.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes it is possible- the fact that the method is native makes no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution.
It is not straight forward but it works =)

```
MethodHandle mh; // a MethodHandle Object
Class<?> mhn;
    try {
        mhn = Class.forName("java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives");
        Constructor<?> con = mhn.getDeclaredConstructor();
        con.setAccessible(true);
        Object mhnInstance = con.newInstance();
        Method getTargetMethod = mhn.getDeclaredMethod("getTargetMethod", new Class<?>[]{MethodHandle.class});
        getTargetMethod.setAccessible(true);
        Method inside = (Method) getTargetMethod.invoke(mhnInstance, mh);
        System.out.println("INSIDE = " + inside.toGenericString());

    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: I've had to use reflection hacks like this before. It's ugly and should be avoided, but sometimes there really is no other way without a LOT of copy and paste. Another option if a class or method is package-private is to declare a wrapper class in the same package in your project with everything public, and forward requests to the package-protected class.