# Invoke private method with java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle

Tags: java, reflection, java-7, invokedynamic, methodhandle

How can I invoke private method using method handles ?

As far as I can see there are only two kinds of publicly accessible `Lookup` instances:

- `MethodHandles.lookup()`
- `MethodHandles.publicLookup()`

and neither allows unrestricted private access.

There is the non-public `Lookup.IMPL_LOOKUP` that does what I want. Is there some public way to obtain it (assuming that SecurityManager allows it) ?

Comment: I'm facing the similar problem (for getters/setters), it will be great if you can share how you managed to call private methods?

Comment: See examples in answers below ?

Comment: It uses reflection to set the accessibility before calling invoke, I was wondering why should do that as lookup() is supposed to give the caller access to direct/private fields and methods as specified in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles.html#lookup%28%29).

Comment: It's only using `setAccessible` to obtain special privileged implementation of `Lookup` that can invoke private members regardless of whether they are accessible to caller.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Turns out it's possible with Lookup#unreflect(Method) and temporarily making method accessible (potentially introducing small security issue unless done during program initialization).

Here is modified main method from Thorben's answer:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Lookup lookup = MethodHandles.lookup();
    NestedTestClass ntc = new Program().new NestedTestClass();

    try {
        // Grab method using normal reflection and make it accessible
        Method pm = NestedTestClass.class.getDeclaredMethod("gimmeTheAnswer");
        pm.setAccessible(true);

        // Now convert reflected method into method handle
        MethodHandle pmh = lookup.unreflect(pm);
        System.out.println("reflection:" + pm.invoke(ntc));

        // We can now revoke access to original method
        pm.setAccessible(false);

        // And yet the method handle still works!
        System.out.println("handle:" + pmh.invoke(ntc));

        // While reflection is now denied again (throws exception)
        System.out.println("reflection:" + pm.invoke(ntc));

    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Better still is to use MethodHandles.privateLookupIn, added in Java SE 9.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know, if this is what you really want. Perhaps you could give some more information about what you want to achieve with it.
But if you want to access `Lookup.IMPL_LOOKUP`, you can do it like in this code sample:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Lookup myLookup = MethodHandles.lookup(); // the Lookup which should be trusted
    NestedTestClass ntc = new Main().new NestedTestClass(); // test class instance

    try {
        Field impl_lookup = Lookup.class.getDeclaredField("IMPL_LOOKUP"); // get the required field via reflections
        impl_lookup.setAccessible(true); // set it accessible
        Lookup lutrusted = (Lookup) impl_lookup.get(myLookup); // get the value of IMPL_LOOKUP from the Lookup instance and save it in a new Lookup object

        // test the trusted Lookup
        MethodHandle pmh = lutrusted.findVirtual(NestedTestClass.class, "gimmeTheAnswer", MethodType.methodType(int.class));
        System.out.println(pmh.invoke(ntc));

    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

// nested class with private method for testing
class NestedTestClass{

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private int gimmeTheAnswer(){

        return 42;
    }
}

}
```

It works with JDK 7, but could break in JDK 8. And be cautious! My antivirus gave an alarm when I executed it.
I think there isn't a public or clean way to do it.

I had a similar issue and finally found a solution: [Access non-public (java-native) classes from JDK (7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16040726/access-non-public-java-native-classes-from-jdk-7).

Comment: I know how to do that, but I have asked for **a public way to obtain it**.

Comment: And by "public way" I mean using public API.

Comment: I don't think that this is possible with a public API. Accessing private fields or methods directly by public methods would break Java's security system.

Comment: No, it wouldn't. You can attempt to access private members USING public API already via `java.lang.reflect.*`. I'm asking about doing the same but with `java.lang.invoke.*`.

Comment: Ah okay, now I think I understand what you want. Yes, Reflections can do this, but with the drawback of enormous security checks. Thus they are a kind of special case. Invokedynamic is mainly built for speed and as far as I know there aren't these security checks like with Reflections. Correct me, if this is wrong. Nevertheless I think the neccessary security checks would destroy invokedynamic's performance goals.

Comment: Avoiding per-call security checks is one of the reasons why I want to use invokedynamic. If there was a public API that can return IMPL_LOOKUP it would only need to perform access check once.

Comment: `IMPL_LOOKUP` is a static field. No need to pass parameter to `Field.get`.

Answer (score -4):

Here's a similiar solution which includes arguments in a private 
function (I just happened to have the code lying around from a previous project):

class name: 
    InspectionTree.java

function signature: 
    private String getSamePackagePathAndName(String className, String classPath)

```
String firstName = "John";
String lastName = "Smith";

//call the class's constructor to set up the instance, before calling the private function
InspectionTree inspectionTree = new InspectionTree(firstName, lastName);

String privateMethodName ="getSamePackagePathAndName";        
Class[] privateMethodArgClasses = new Class[] { String.class, String.class };

Method method = 
         inspectionTree.getClass().getDeclaredMethod(privateMethodName, privateArgClasses);

method.setAccessible(true);

String className = "Person";
String classPath = "C:\\workspace";

Object[] params = new Object[]{className, classPath};        

//note the return type of function 'getSamePackagePathAndName' is a String, so we cast
//the return type here as a string
String answer=  (String)method.invoke(inspectionTree, params);

method.setAccessible(false);
```

Comment: And where should this misterious InspectionTree come from?