# Method Class in Reflection API

Tags: java

This program ran fine when `test()` method was `public` but as soon as I changed its modifier to `private` it showed Run time error.Can anybody explain why?

```
 package ObjectClass;
 import java.lang.reflect.Method;

 public class reflect8 {

      public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

           Class c1 = Class.forName("ObjectClass.Reflect8A");

           Object obj = c1.newInstance();

           Method m1 = c1.getDeclaredMethod("test");

           m1.invoke(obj);

   }
}

class Reflect8A {

       private void test() {

           System.out.println("from test...");
       }
   }
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19135218/invoke-private-method-with-java-lang-invoke-methodhandle

Comment: Well of course it does. Do you know what `private` means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is why you need to call `setAccessible(true)` even if `getDeclaredMethod` returns the private method.

[Javadoc of `getDeclaredMethod`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethods--) (emphasis mine):

> Returns an array containing Method objects reflecting all the declared methods of the class or interface represented by this Class object, ***including public, protected, default (package) access, and private methods***, but excluding inherited methods.

[Javadoc of `invoke`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object...-):

> Throws IllegalAccessException - if this Method object is enforcing Java language access control and the underlying method is inaccessible.

[Javadoc of `setAccessible`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html#setAccessible-boolean-) (emphasis mine):

> Set the accessible flag for this object to the indicated boolean value. ***A value of true indicates that the reflected object should suppress Java language access checking when it is used.***

Answer (score 3):

```
 Method m1 = c1.getDeclaredMethod("test");
 m1.setAccessible(true);
 m1.invoke(obj);
```

Comment: @Tkachur_evgen,it worked  but since we r getting an instance of a class at runtime, why can't we access private methods through that instance without calling setAccessible(true)

Comment: @Aamir, because private modifier specifies that member can only be accessed within its own class