# Java 8 access private member with lambda?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

[Invoke private method with java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19135218/invoke-private-method-with-java-lang-invoke-methodhandle) gives an answer to private member access, while [Java access bean methods with LambdaMetafactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27602758/java-access-bean-methods-with-lambdametafactory) gives an answer to lambda based member access. However, by combining the two, I still can not find a way to access private members via lambda. The error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: member is private: XXX from ZZZ
at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.revealDirect(MethodHandles.java:1353)
at java.lang.invoke.AbstractValidatingLambdaMetafactory.<init>(AbstractValidatingLambdaMetafactory.java:131)
at java.lang.invoke.InnerClassLambdaMetafactory.<init>(InnerClassLambdaMetafactory.java:155)
at java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(LambdaMetafactory.java:299)
```

points to [revealDirect](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles.Lookup.html#revealDirect-java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle-) which is part of [metafactory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/LambdaMetafactory.html#metafactory-java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles.Lookup-java.lang.String-java.lang.invoke.MethodType-java.lang.invoke.MethodType-java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle-java.lang.invoke.MethodType-) call site builder. How can I customize the builder to control its access checks?

**UPDATE**: Example of [Working Solution Option #3](https://gist.github.com/Andrei-Pozolotin/dc8b448dc590183f5459) per [Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2711488/holger)

Comment: You should provide the specific code which throws the exception. Generally I would be surprised if it turned out that you can customize any aspect of the behavior of lambdas. The semantics of the lambda syntax are subject to precise specification in the JLS.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The critical part is the `Lookup` object that is passed to the `LambdaMetafactory` on which then `revealDirect` is invoked.

From the [documententation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles.Lookup.html#revealDirect-java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle-):

> Security and access checks are performed to ensure that this lookup object is capable of reproducing the target method handle. This means that the cracking may fail if target is a direct method handle but was created by an unrelated lookup object.

As a consequence, lambda expression can only access methods accessible by the class containing the lambda expression as the JVM provided `Lookup` object will reflect exactly these access permissions.

This also works for Java Beans methods as these are `public` by convention.

---

So if you want to invoke `private` methods you have three options:

- Generate the lambda instance from within the declaring class of the `private` method which has access to it. When this class calls [`MethodHandles.lookup()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles.html#lookup--) it will get an appropriate `Lookup` instance

  A class may also create such a `Lookup` instance with the desired capabilities and hand it over to another (trusted) class which may use it to perform such reflective operations. This is exactly what happens implicitly when an `invokedynamic` instruction is executed. A class containing `invokedynamic` instructions pointing to a bootstrap method within `LambdaMetaFactory` implies such trust.

  So using all-ordinary operations, its always the class having the access permissions which has to enable the access for another class
- Starting with Java 9, use [`MethodHandles.privateLookupIn(Class, MethodHandles.Lookup)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles.html#privateLookupIn-java.lang.Class-java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles.Lookup-) to acquire a method handle with private access rights on the specified target class. This is checked against the module access rules. For access within the same module, this should always succeed.
- Use even more black magic to get hands on an appropriate `Lookup` instance. The question you have linked mentions the non-`public` `Lookup.IMPL_LOOKUP`. If you get hands on this instance and call [`in(declaringClass)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles.Lookup.html#in-java.lang.Class-) on it, you get an instance with the desired properties. Alternatively you can create a restricted lookup object via [`MethodHandles.publicLookup()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles.html#publicLookup--) `.in(declaringClass)` and overwrite its access modifiers (the ones reported by [`lookupModes()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles.Lookup.html#lookupModes--) to enable full access. Obviously, both require access override on fields that are not part of the `public` Java API.

Comment: Thank you for the pointers @holger. We have no control of the target class, so your Option 1 does not apply. Option 2 works fine, reproduced here: [PrivateTargetLambda.java](https://gist.github.com/Andrei-Pozolotin/dc8b448dc590183f5459) Do you think there is a way to avoid "black magic" or Option 2 would be a final answer?