# Java 8 generic LambdaMetafactory?

Tags: java, generics, lambda, java-8

While converting [Java 8 access private member with lambda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28184065/java-8-access-private-member-with-lambda) from [concrete format](https://gist.github.com/Andrei-Pozolotin/dc8b448dc590183f5459) to [generic format](https://gist.github.com/Andrei-Pozolotin/419df7d78ca6ec4e6c28) I found [another limitation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandle.html) :

> To issue a complete symbolic type descriptor, the compiler must also
>   determine the return type. This is **based on a cast on the method
>   invocation expression**, if there is one, or else Object if the
>   invocation is an expression or else void if the invocation is a
>   statement.

I am curious if there is a way to [overcome this](https://gist.github.com/Andrei-Pozolotin/419df7d78ca6ec4e6c28#file-privatetargetlambdageneric-java-L61)?

**UPDATE**: [Working Example](https://gist.github.com/Andrei-Pozolotin/6be08c431511c4813f63) per [Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2711488/holger)

Comment: Sure. Just use `invoke` rather than `invokeExact`.

Comment: Yes, it works, thank you @Holger. Does `invoke` vs `invokeExact` introduce boxing/unboxing or performance **penalty**?

Comment: That obviously depends on the *required* conversions, e.g. converting `ToIntFunction` to `Object` does not require any boxing. Since you are using the `MethodHandle` exactly one time it doesn’t make sense to think about performance; even `invokeExact` will be rather slow (compared to an ordinary method invocation) for a particular handle. Only when you are going to invoke *the same* method handle very often, you may consider using `asType` once so you can use `invokeExact` multiple times afterwards, like described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22321671/2711488)

Comment: Maybe I should emphasize that `invoke` is *signature-polymorphic* just like `invokeExact`, hence doesn’t require boxing or varargs handling like, e.g. `invokeWithArguments`. The difference is that `invoke` *allows* conversions and will do boxing/unboxing *if required* while `invokeExact` requires an exact match of the invoke type signature and the handle’s type signature.

Comment: In other words: once LambdaMetafactory has [produced the lambda](https://gist.github.com/Andrei-Pozolotin/6be08c431511c4813f63#file-privatetargetlambdaworking-java-L91), there will be no performance/boxing penalty (except for 1 level of indirection) during the [lambda usage](https://gist.github.com/Andrei-Pozolotin/6be08c431511c4813f63#file-privatetargetlambdaworking-java-L141), am I correct? @Holger please enter the answer, so I can mark this complete.

Comment: Just to clarify: I want to make sure that whatever approach `invoke` or `invokeExact` is used with `LambdaMetafactory` to construct the lambda instance, it will not affect the resulting lambada internals in such a way that it will introduce unexpected boxing or performance penalty inside the lambda.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `invoke` instead of `invokeExact` if your compile-time invocation signature does not match the `invokedType` parameter you have passed to the `LambdaMetafactory`. It will perform required conversions.

There is no performance penalty regarding the actual invocation of the lambda instance’s method. The decision how the generated lambda will work is made by the `LambdaMetafactory` before the `CallSite` encapsulating the `MethodHandle` is returned. Hence, the way you invoke it to construct the lambda instance does not influence the result.